# What does breach protocol time bonus affect?

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

The breach protocol time can be increased by skills and items.

E.g. the reward for 3rd level of Breach Protocol is: "Increases Breach Protocol Time by 5%."

But what exactly does the **breach protocol time** affect?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Breach Protocol time is the amount of time you get to breach a network by completing the network mini puzzle.

I have cyberwear which doubles the time.

[image: Cyberwear mod to add 100% time]

This leads to a timer of 70 seconds

[image: 70 second breach timer]

However, when I remove the mod I only get 30 seconds.

[image: 30 second breach timer]

Comment: Yep, thats it. Only the mini-game time is increased. As for me, it is a pretty useless buff as the mini-games are really easy and the time do not even start from the very beginning but after the first number is in the buffer.

Comment: @ViktorBe Indeed, that seems like a bug to me; it would be much more of a challenge if the timer started as soon as you opened it!

Answer (score 4):

According to [this wiki](https://cyberpunk2077.wiki.fextralife.com/Hacking) the breach protocol time is **the time you get to finish the Breach Protocol mini-game**.

> The Breach Protocol mini-game enables you to hack each network you
> encounter. While standard quickhacks usually work on single targets,
> the Breach Protocol quickhack has the unique benefit of affecting all
> targets in the network.
>
> ...
>
> You can improve, your chances of success in various ways:
>
> - **By extending the breach time (the amount of time you have to complete
>   each puzzle)**.
> - ...